Cutting and plugging disconnected gas-line pipe internally
Gas line coming into the house by ultility company and new line was run. Old gas line protrudes from cinder block wall about 2 ft. I want to cut pipe and seal it inside of the pipe. What can I use to seal pipe internally?

You haven't told us what the "gas line" is. Please revise to be more clear.

An empty unused pipe can be sealed with almost anything that will fit.  What it depends on is what you are sealing it from?  Just air, or water, or bugs/mice.  Mice might need something more dependable than bubble gum/foam.

I would cut it off flush with the wall and fill with expandable foam, like Mouse shield, or its equivalent.

I much prefer plain silicone. For one thing, you don't have to kill an entire can of foam for a tiny fill. For another, foam rarely does well on an exterior wall.

The product is formulated specifically for closing an exterior entry into the home.  Plus it come with a reusable straw, so now you can use part of a can and reuse more later. Praise the new straw technology!

Reuse more later is usually limited to a short period(month/s) of time.

agreed, however it is still better than the old "once you use it , you better use it all" problems.

Generally gas lines are steel pipe.  You can use an angle grinder or reciprocating saw to cut it flush to the wall.
Foam isn't great environment wise.  I avoid if I can.  For something like this I'd use Gardner bender Duct Seal or something similar.  Throw some steel wool into the hole first to deter any rodent activity.
